# Laravel eloquent relation search using child table record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Problem :**

I want only that records where relational records [ `user` ] not null.

In my case **I want only first record**. where `user` is not null

Result:
[image]

**User Table**

- id
- name
- email

**Project Tabel**

- id
- title
- user_id `[foreign key]`

My code is like this

```
$projects = App\Project::with(['user' => function ($user) {
                    $user->where('name', '=', 'Ketan');
                }])
                ->get();

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    echo $project->title.' - '.$project;
}
```

My result is like this : 
[image]

Comment: Do you need to get only one project (any project) where user is not `null`?

Comment: Yes, @AlexeyMezenin. i want any project where user is not null. 

whenever i apply this condition on result. i found 

6 results on 1st page, 
5 results on 2nd page, 
8 results on 3rd page,
so on.....

so, **i want to apply this condition on query not on results.**

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working

```
$projects = App\Project::whereHas('user', function ($user) {
              $user->where('name', '=', 'Ketan');
           }])->get();
```

**Change 'with' to 'whereHas' and note that whereHas doesn't accept the array as the param**
For reference [Laracasts Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-model-where-latest-hasmany-equals-a-value)

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$projects = App\Project::with(['user' => function ($user) {
                    $user->where('name', '=', 'Ketan');
                }])
                ->get();

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    if($project->user != null){
        echo $project->title.' - '.$project;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution. It will load every project from the database, for you to then loop through and only print out those with a user.

Answer (score -1):

**I got solution of my question**

```
$projects = App\Project::whereHas(['user' => function ($user) {          <--Change Here
                    $user->where('name', '=', 'Ketan');
                }])
                ->get();
```

Only **Change 'with' to 'whereHas'**

By this solution, I have got only those Project records in which user ( relational record ) is not null.